# dialogflow ambiguity with same synonyms for different entity values

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an issue developing an agent with dialogflow (api.ai). I am using a lot of entity values which are all different from one another. however there are similar synonyms for some entity values but the agent is returning only one value.

How can i get all the possible matches or ask question to resolve the ambiguity

for example i have an intent like: tell me the location of ABC express train

```
if my entity values are :
entity            synonym
15127             ABC express
12345             ABC express
```

I want it to return two values or ask question to resolve such ambiguity 
how can i work this out
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not enough information. Post some example which will have entities, synonyms etc.

Comment: I think i provided enough information. My concern is if i have many entity values  with same synonym how can i deal with such a situation. api.ai is giving me only one entity value that it finds and not providing with all such matches    similar issue is provided in the link if you find it useful  https://discuss.api.ai/t/synonym-in-multiple-instances-of-one-entity/711

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enable fulfillment for this intent, you can take a look at the value the user said and ask a further question if you need to disambiguate between entities.

Let's imagine you are extracting an entity called "trains". The parameters table in your intent might look like this:

[image: Image of parameters table]

By default, if the user says `ABC express`, the fulfillment webhook will be called with the following parameter hash:

```
"parameters": {
  "trains": "15127"
}
```

This isn't enough information to decide if the request was ambiguous, since train 15127 might also have non-ambiguous synonyms.

You can configure Dialogflow to send the original text of the entity, alongside the resolved value. This means you will receive the following information to your webhook:

```
"parameters": {
  "trains": "15127",
  "original": "ABC express"
}
```

You can then use some simple logic to ask a further question if the value of `original` appears in a list of known ambiguous synonyms.

To have Dialogflow send this data, modify your parameters table so it looks like the following:

[image: Image of parameters table]

This will cause the original synonym to be sent to Dialogflow alongside the resolved value.