# outputContexts sometimes does not appear in queryResult

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an agent project at Dialogflow v2. And my code evaluates the agent via Web API (I use python code without any dialogflow libraries).

To check the original value of an entity, I use `outputContexts` in `queryResult` by `detectIntent` function.

But I found that `queryResult` sometimes does not contain `outputContexts`. The results depend on Intents of the input text. I use custom entities and system entities in my agent. And I found `sys.date` entity sometimes does not return `outputContexts` via web API. 
However, it returns `outputContexts` when I tested the same input text via Dialogflow GUI console.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/DetectIntentResponse?hl=ja

> outputContexts[]: object(Context)
>   The collection of output contexts. If applicable,
>   outputContexts.parameters contains entries with name .original containing the original parameter values before the
>   query.

### Update 1

I found `outputContexts` only appear when some **required** slots are missing in the dialog. For example, `intentA` contains two required slots. If I input a text includes only one slot, the response shows `outputContexts`, and if the text includes two slots (all slots, i.e., `allRequiredParamsPresent=True`), the response does not show `outputContexts`. Is that true? It is difficult to read this specification from Dialogflow document.

### Update 2

I found a nice solution to obtain original entity values from the below thread. To obtain the original values, I need to prepare special entities to extract `original` data from arbitrary slots. This `original` is applicable for system and custom entities.

[dialogflow ambiguity with same synonyms for different entity values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960875/dialogflow-ambiguity-with-same-synonyms-for-different-entity-values)

Comment: That seems odd. Can you update the question to include a concrete example of the call you're making, a screen shot of the Intent it should match, and the response you're getting that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Hi! Could you see my updated question? I found the rule. It is very difficult to show whole data of my agent because of confidential matters. I am so sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#required) if you enable [webhook slot filling](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook-slot-filling) you will receive a request with every parameter for every missing required parameter. Additionally, to complement the response [you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978637/7517757), it is no longer necessary to add an additional `original` entity in the parameters, the [outputContext parameters will include it](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#queryresult).

Here is an example of parameters:

[image: Paramters]
And the outputContext:

[image: Context]