# Is Ambiguous entity identified with input context?

Tags: dialogflow-es

My question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960875/dialogflow-ambiguity-with-same-synonyms-for-different-entity-values) 
, but it should be different because my question relates to the combination of entities and context.

Let me show an example; here duplicated synonyms are:

```
| Entity      | Value       | Synonyms     |
|-------------+-------------+--------------|
| whether     | whether     | fine, cloudy |
| granularity | granularity | fine, coarse |
```

And I have same training phrase on different intents with different input context as follows:

- Intent-a:

  - input context: `A`
  - training phrase: `is it <fine>?`
  - synonym `<fine>` is for `@whether`
- Intent-b:

  - input context: `B`
  - training phrase: `is it <fine>?`
  - synonym `<fine>` is for `@granularity`

When a user says "is it fine?" under the context 'A', `fine` is identified to @whether?  Or, input context is not considered on intent-detection for user input sentence so that is it fifty-fifty which intent is detected?

Answer (score 1):

Context is considered when identifying the intents. Therefore if you have properly defined the contexts for the above scenario no ambiguity is created.

Comment: So, under context-A, @whether entity should be choosed, right?

Comment: Yes. If the previous entity has an output context of A, it will be identified as the weather.